# How to do null check in where condition if parameter value or cell value is null

Tags: sql-server

How to do null check in where condition if parameter value or cell value is null

```
--Update into BudCustomers from Bulk
Update BudCustomers
 set    BudCustomers.ImportedRecord = ImportedRecord
       ,BudCustomers.VersionID = @VersionId
       ,BudCustomers.STATUSID = @StatusId
FROM BudCustomers BCUST
JOIN External_Blk_Itm_Contracts EBIC ON BCUST.LegalName = EBIC.CustomerName
Where     BCUST.ImportedRecord <> @ImportedRecord
       OR BCUST.STATUSID <> @StatusId
```

Comment: you can use ISNULL or COALESCE

Comment: how i can apply to this above query

Comment: doesnt work this above

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not apparent how the question relates to the code shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where ((BCUST.ImportedRecord <> @ImportedRecord) OR (BCUST.ImportedRecord IS NULL AND @ImportedRecord IS NULL))
```

And then same pattern for other column/parameter pairs.

Comment: what if one is null and one is not null?